# Why does the Bison always output a greater-than symbol? How to omit it?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I created a Bison parser to convert input data to XML. Whenever I run my parser the output contains the XML and following the XML is this symbol:

```
>
```

Yikes! That greater-than symbol makes the XML not well-formed.

What is producing that greater-than symbol? How do I tell Bison to not generate it? I don't think there is anything in my "main" function that tells Bison to output a greater-than symbol:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    yyparse();
    
    fclose(yyin);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'What is producing that greater-than symbol?' Something in your code. 'I don't think there is anything in my "main" function that tells Bison to output a greater-than symbol' Indeed, there's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you are using (f)lex and none of your lexer patterns match the `>`, so the default action is used. The (f)lex default action is to print unmatched characters on `yyout`, which is often undesirable.

I recommend always using `%option nodefault` in your flex files. That will cause flex to issue a warning if anything could trigger the default rule (and it changes the default rule to a fatal error). Unfortunately it doesn't actually tell you which characters can't be matched, but you should be able to figure that out by looking at your rules.

A good debugging technique is to compile a version of your scanner with debugging traces, and then write a simple wrapper which just calls `yylex` in a loop until it returns 0. (Printing out the tokens returned is more work but can be useful, too.) Run that with test inputs until you are satisfied that the scanner is working as per expectation.

Bison also has a trace facility, described in the bison manual in the "debugging your parser" chapter. It can also help you debug scanner issues, but you have to wade through a lot more debug logging.

Comment: Hello @rici Yes, I am using Flex. My input does not contain the > symbol (I am converting a non-XML file to XML). Per your suggestion, I added %option nodefault but my output continues to end with newline then >.

Comment: @roger: ok, then you'll have to debug your parser :-). The debugging traces will be useful. Trying to crystal ball problems with no supporting documentation at all is not so easy; my clairvoyant powers are sadly limited.

Comment: Hi @rici Okay I will investigate further. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again @rici Just wanted to let you know, I found the culprit. Here is the action for the start rule: { printf("<RunwayStatus>%s</RunwayStatus>\n> ", $5); } Notice the greater-than symbol following \n ... oops!